# php script blocks when trying to add second e-mail adress

Tags: php, phpmailer

php script blocks when trying to add second e-mail adress

i am trying to create a simple form that collects a name and a email adress and send it wit php mail.

When sending with one email adress it works perfectly
but when trying to add a second mail adress to send to it blocks.

```
<?php
$message = ""; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "test@test.be"; // Your email address
    $Voor = $_POST['Voornaam'];
    $Achter = $_POST['Achternaam'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    
    $message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='800' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10' bordercolor='#B3B3B3'>
    <tr style='background: #eee;'>
        <td style='font: 24px Arial, sans-serif' bgcolor='#B3B3B3' colspan='2'>
            <strong>Details</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='font: 15px Arial, sans-serif' width='200px' bgcolor='#B3B3B3'><strong>Naam:</strong></td>
        <td style='font: 15px Arial, sans-serif' width='600px'>".$_POST['Voornaam']." ".$_POST['Achternaam']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='font: 15px Arial, sans-serif' width='200px' bgcolor='#B3B3B3'><strong>Email:</strong></td>
        <td style='font: 15px Arial, sans-serif' width='600px'>".$_POST['email']."</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>";
    
    $subject = "Contact Form Details ".$_POST['Voornaam']." ".$_POST['Achternaam'].
    
    // Set content-type header for sending HTML email 
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    
    $headers .= "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
    
    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if ($result) {
        // $message = "Your Message was sent Successfully!";
        header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your Message was sent Successfully!");</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = window.location.href;</script>';

    }else{
        // $message = "Sorry! Message was not sent, Try again Later.";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Sorry! Message was not sent, Try again Later.");</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = window.location.href;</script>';
    }
    // header('Location: contact.php');
}

?>
```

I tried:

```
$to = "test@test.be, test1@test.be";
```

and tried adding: `$headers .="CC: test2@test.be";` under from header

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You tagged this with `phpmailer`, please use that instead of `mail`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: hey, i've been trying to get PHPmailer to work but i am no wizard in PHP.